# How to save and show 2d numpy array as an RGB pseudo colored image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, save

I have a large size 2d numpy array (*size = (2000, 2000)*) with only five possible values *1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0* and *5.0*. I want to save and show this array as an image in RGB colored format, here each unique value of array should be represented by different color. Please help i am a beginner to python.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `PIL.Image` to do that, but first transform your array.

You could say for example, that:

1. 1.0 Should be red, represented as (255,0,0)
2. 2.0 Should be green -> (0,255,0)
3. 3.0 Should be blue -> (0,0,255)
4. 4.0 Should be black -> (0,0,0)
5. 5.0 Should be white -> (255,255,255)

You could of course change those values to whatever colors you choose, but this is just for demonstration. That being said, your 2-d array also needs to be "flattened" to 1-d for PIL.Image to accept it as data.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
your_2d_array = np.something() # Replace this line, obviously
img_array = []
for x in your_2d_array.reshape(2000*2000):
    if x == 1.0:
        img_array.append((255,0,0)) # RED
    elif x == 2.0:
        img_array.append((0,255,0)) # GREEN
    elif x == 3.0:
        img_array.append((0,0,255)) # BLUE
    elif x == 4.0:
        img_array.append((0,0,0)) # BLACK
    elif x == 5.0:
        img_array.append((255,255,255)) # WHITE

img = Image.new('RGB',(2000,2000))
img.putdata(img_array)
img.save('somefile.png')
```

While this should work, I think there are more efficient ways to do this that I do not know, So I will be glad if someone edits this answer with better examples. But if it's a small app and maximum efficiency doesn't bother you, here it is.

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` is useful for tasks like this, though there are other ways. 
 Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image

src = np.zeros((200,200))
print src.shape

rgb = np.zeros((200,200,3))
print rgb.shape

src[10,10] = 1
src[20,20] = 2
src[30,30] = 3

for i in range(src.shape[0]):
  for j in range(src.shape[1]):
    rgb[i,j,0] = 255 if src[i,j]==1 else 0 # R
    rgb[i,j,1] = 255 if src[i,j]==2 else 0 # G
    rgb[i,j,2] = 255 if src[i,j]==3 else 0 # B

matplotlib.image.imsave('test.png', rgb.astype(np.uint8))
```

The trick is to convert it to an RGB array of shape `(x, y, 3)`.  You can use any formula you want to gen the per-pixel RGB values.

Also, note converting it to an `uint8` array.

Comment: Sir, i am newly registered on stackoverflow.com.  I have already accepted your answer, as soon as i got more than 15 reputation. my acceptance will be appeared. Again thank you for helping me

Comment: btw, doing O(m*n) individual assignments like this is fairly inefficient in numpy.  i did it that way for clarity, but some creative combination of array operations will likely be an order of magnitude faster.  (but also largely unintelligible.)  i wouldn't worry about it though unless you see a real-world performance issue.

Comment: It would be batter if i found any faster way to do this. Right Now I am working on a pixel be pixel classification of SAR image, i am using SVM classifier for that, and originally asked problem is to from an image from predicted labels. There can be some modules to do this task if i find i will do that way.