# How to I make a image from numpy array in python?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

I want to map each numpy array to a color to create an image.
For example: if I have the numpy array:

```
[ [0 0 1 3] 
[0 2 4 5]
[1 2 3 6] ]
```

I want to make an image by mapping all values below 3 to blue like

```
[ [blue blue sky-blue green]
[blue sky-blue green green] 
[blue sky-blue green green]
```

Comment: This is answered fairly well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890720/how-to-save-and-show-2d-numpy-array-as-an-rgb-pseudo-colored-image

Answer (score 2):

You can make a two-color color map. Then make an array with 1 or 0 depending on your condition and pass both to `pyplot.imshow()`:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

# white and blue
color = ListedColormap([(1,1,1), (0,0,1)])

a = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1, 3], 
    [0, 2, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 6] 
])

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(a < 3, cmap=color)
```

[image]

Comment: Can i make 3-4 colors with this?

Comment: Yes. You an make a colormap with more colors, or use one of the built-in ones. Then you need an array with more values describing where to use the colors.

Comment: Can you give an example for 4 color map?